# JQuery datatable index is coming as a NaN

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable, datatables

Here, I'm trying to get `id` and `index` for a my button action, but my index is coming as `NaN`.

Here is my console output:

[image]

Comment: your index is not declared yet where you sum it up by 1.

Comment: index of what ..  row or column ?

Comment: Please put the actual code in your question to make it easier to decipher and for us to give you better answers! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need this, as per my understanding.

```
meta.row;

"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    var index= meta.row;
},
```

Comment: it is solved now by using this var index = meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart; but your answer also true thanks :) +1

Comment: please accept the answer if it helps to you. @UrvashiBhatt

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `index` variable then increment it by 1.

```
var index = 0;
index = index + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Index must be assigned a value that can increment Numbers.

```
var index = null;
index += 1;
```

Comment: indeed! null can be used if you dont know the value yet and can increment with numbers. If null isnt changed it will work as 0. so 0 + 1 = 1;